# query for all paths with a set of specified relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query a graph to return all of the paths with a set of specified relationships.

The graph I have contains the following nodes: Person

The relationships which connect two people are: knows, married

So an example of some data are:

```
c:Person-[:knows]->b:Person
  a:Person-[:married]->c:Person
  d:Person-[knows]-> a:Person
```

In my query I would like to be able to find all paths that contain both relationships 'knows' and 'married'; however, I don't care about the ordering of such relationships in the paths. For example, my query should return the following paths:

1) a:Person-[:married]->c:Person-[:knows]->b:Person
 2) d:Person-[:knows]->a:Person-[:married]->c:Person

I tried the following query

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:KNOWS|MARRIED*1..3]-(b)
  RETURN p
```

However, it returned the paths only having knows relationship or the paths only having married relationship, but not both.

Is there any way of finding the paths I want? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
MATCH p=(a)-[rel*]-(b)
WHERE type(rel)='KNOWS' OR type(rel)='MARRIED'
RETURN p
```

It will provide you all paths

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried the query and it threw out an error: r not defined (line 2, column 7).

Comment: Thank you again for the updated answer. I tried and it still threw out the same error:rel not defined. However, I found the following query can work:

match (a)-[r*] -(b)
where 
    filter(x IN r where type(x)='KNOWS')
  AND
    filter(y IN r where type(y)='MARRIED')
return r

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH p = (a:Person)-[rels:KNOWS|MARRIED*]->(b:Person)
WITH p, EXTRACT(r IN rels | TYPE(r)) AS types
WHERE 'KNOWS' IN types AND 'MARRIED' IN types
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicole. I tried the query, no rows were returned.

Comment: Guess that pattern doesn't exist, then. :P